# Error in installing Pillow into PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm, pip

Я новичок в вебе. В пайчарме возникли проблемы модулем Pillow. В `venv` модуль отображается как инсталлированный, но при запуске приложения/проведений миграций поднимается ошибка. В чем может быть дело?

```
(venv) C:\Users\grigo\PycharmProjects\PhoForum>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\grigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\grigo\PycharmProjects\PhoForum\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\grigo\PycharmProjects\PhoForum\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\grigo\PycharmProjects\PhoForum\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 469, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
mainapp.Task.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

[image: ```]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pip install Pillow` попробуйте из терминала ide. всегда работало

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло

Comment: Создайте чистый venv через Settings > Project Interpreter. После этого ставьте Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что версия питона 3.9, а ты запускаешь с проектом джанговым созданным под 3.8, а у них нет обратной совместимости и это грустно(

- Установи python3.8
- `rm venv\*`
- python3.8 -m vitualenv venv
- source venv/scripts/activate
- Вауля, все работает